# Type of the objects inside a Ruby 'each' block

Tags: ruby

I'am doing a little app to download the torrents from an XML feed.

I was able to parse the XML file, but I have a little problem with an array.

I create an array with the links of the torrents I want to download and iterate it. However, inside the `each` block, the item isn't a String. Ruby says that the type of the object is Array.

some snippet of code:

```
series = ['Fringe', 'Supernatural', 
          'The.Walking.Dead', 'Dexter', 
          'Game.of.Thrones', 'Merlin.2008']
links = ['http://torrentday.com/asdada/asdad/torrent',
         'http://torrentday.com/t5terter/Fringe.s08e02.torrent']
links.each do |link|
  series.each do |serie|
    if link.include? serie # doesn't work, because the type 
                           # of link is Array, not String.
      downloader.download(link)
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Whatever is doing the parsing is doing that: the type inside the block is whatever is in the collection.

Comment: Also include a mock data-source for `links` and `series`. As it is now ... it's magic 8-ball sort of question.

Comment: is just an example, @niklas-baumstark.

Comment: code works for me. And why shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.8, is there any kind of trouble with this?

Comment: What is the output if you put a `puts link.inspect` inside the `links.each` block?

Comment: As-is I don't see how this can fail. I return you to my original comment.

Comment: @BrandonTilley thanks man, i found the error. When a parse the XML with the links, I was adding the item to array, i was doing something like `links.push item['link']`, but the `item['link']` return a array with one element. So, the problem is here, and thanks to your question i can found it. Thanks :)

Comment: @caarlos0: always run your full sample code to make sure it doesn't work before you post it.

Comment: Also, the legality of downloading these files depends on where you live.  Don't just assume laws where you live exist everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appeared to work just fine for me:

```
> series = ['Fringe', 'Supernatural', 
*           'The.Walking.Dead', 'Dexter', 
*           'Game.of.Thrones', 'Merlin.2008']
=> ["Fringe", "Supernatural", "The.Walking.Dead", "Dexter", "Game.of.Thrones", "Merlin.2008"]
> links = ['http://torrentday.com/asdada/asdad/torrent',
*          'http://torrentday.com/t5terter/Fringe.s08e02.torrent']
=> ["http://torrentday.com/asdada/asdad/torrent", "http://torrentday.com/t5terter/Fringe.s08e02.torrent"]
> links.each do |link|
*   series.each do |serie|
*     if link.include? serie # doesn't work, because the type 
>       puts "#{link} included #{serie}"
>     end
>   end
> end
http://torrentday.com/t5terter/Fringe.s08e02.torrent included Fringe
=> ["http://torrentday.com/asdada/asdad/torrent", "http://torrentday.com/t5terter/Fringe.s08e02.torrent"]
```

It properly executed the body of the `if` statement for the one matching combination of `serie` and `link`.